# Working with state on recursive components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

I'm writing a component that renders itself inside recursively and is data-driven

Attaching my [sandbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/seb-custom-filter-builder-l5mf2z), as it will be easier to see there.

This is my data:

```
var builderStructureData = [
  {
    id: 123,
    value: 3,
    children: []
  },
  {
    id: 345,
    value: 5,
    children: [
      {
        id: 4123,
        value: 34,
        children: [
          {
            id: 342342,
            value: 33,
            children: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 340235,
        value: 3431,
        children: [
          {
            id: 342231342,
            value: 3415,
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

and it renders like this:

[image]

This is my App.js:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Group from "./components/group";
import builderStructureData from "./components/builderStructureData";

function App() {
  const [builderStructure, setBuilderStructure] = useState(
    builderStructureData
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {builderStructure.map((x) => {
        return <Group key={x.id} children={x.children} value={x.value} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my recursive component:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Group(props) {
  let childrenArray = [];
  if (props.children) {
    props.children.map((x) => childrenArray.push(x));
  }

  return (
    <div className="group" draggable>
      <p>this is value: </p>
      <input value={props.value} readOnly={true}></input>
      <button>Add Group</button>

      {childrenArray.map((x) => {
        return <Group key={x.id} children={x.children} value={x.value} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I can render the components based on the data, and it seems to be handling recursion fine. I need to store the state on the App.js page and be able to change it from within child components. For example, if I update the "value" field of the component with ID = 342342, I want it to update that corresponding object in the state no matter how deeply nested it is, but not sure how to do that as it is not as simple as just passing a prop.

Am I taking the right approach with my code snippet? How can I do the state update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking this in a wrong way, it should be very easy to do what you want.

The most imported thing is to make a little small changes in `Group`
Please have a look

```js
import React from "react";

export default function Group(props) {
  const [item, setItem] = React.useState(props.item);
  let childrenArray = [];
  if (item.children) {
    item.children.map((x) => childrenArray.push(x));
  }
  
  const updateValue = ()=> {
      // this will update the value of the current object 
      // no matter how deep its recrusive is and the update will also happen in APP.js
      // now you should also use datacontext in app.js togather with state if you want to 
      // trigger somethings in app.js
      item.value =props.item.value= 15254525;
      setState({...item}) // update the state now 
  }

  return (
    <div className="group" draggable>
      <p>this is value: </p>
      <input value={item.value} readOnly={true}></input>
      <button>Add Group</button>

      {childrenArray.map((x) => {
        return <Group item={x} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The code above should make you understand how easy it is to think about this as an object instead of keys.

Hop this should make it easy for you to understand

Comment: Alen I like this approach but I'm not exactly sure what you mean in your snippet, for example this piece:

      item.value =props.item.value= 15254525;

Would you be able to fork my snippet from sandox and update it there?

here's my snipptet:
https://codesandbox.io/s/seb-custom-filter-builder-l5mf2z

Comment: Sure, add a bounty and I will make time to rewrite your code for you :)

Comment: Will be eligible for bounty tomorrow, and will likely raise it. I managed to update the state on App.js but it doesn't fire automatically, trying to fire it through useEffect. It definately works when I fire it from a button click event.

Comment: That is why I said use datacontext with state.

Comment: Yes, I remember that, I tried that and it still doesn't fire, I must be doing something wrong.  This is my updated snippet https://codesandbox.io/s/seb-custom-filter-builder-2-gtvrvn 

If I don't resolve it myself I'll add a bounty. If I make it work myself will accept your answer of course

Also, when you say datacontext do you mean useContext hook?

Comment: Yes, you wrap the whole app in a context that exist in app. Js and useContext to control a trigger in app.js

Answer (score 3):

I would advise the state normalization approach - here is an example for redux state - https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape - but you can use this approach with your state. So - your state will look like this:

```js
state = {
  items: {
    [123]: {
      id: 123,
      value: 3,
      childrenIds: []
    },
    [345]: {
      id: 345,
      value: 5,
      childrenIds: [4123, 340235]
    },
    [4123]: {
      id: 4123,
      value: 34,
      parentId: 345,
      childrenIds: [342342]
    },
    [342342]: {
      id: 342342,
      value: 33,
      parentId: 4123,
      childrenIds: []
    },
    [340235]: {
      id: 340235,
      value: 3431,
      parentId: 345,
      childrenIds: [342231342]
    },
    [342231342]: {
      id: 342231342,
      value: 3415,
      parentId: 340235
      childrenIds: []
    }
  }
}
```

Here the field "*childrenIds*" is an optional denormalization for ease of use, if you want - you can do without this field. With this approach, there will be no problem updating the state.

Comment: This looks good but I will try to go with Alen.Toma's solution, because I need to preserve the same object structure and it seemed more familiar

Comment: I don't believe that anyone really needs to preserve the same structure - but thats your choice, so - good luck!)